# 404 (Invalid SID value) in Strophe while using attach()

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I have searched in google and some similar questions on stack overflow. But I am not getting any solution.

Basically, I want to persist connection across web pages in my application. For this I am using cookies. I store SID and RID in cookies and use them for attaching the session again.

Below is my code.

```
this.openConnection = function(){
        if (chatObj.connection != null) return;


        var jid = chatObj.userName + '@' + chatObj.openfireDomainURL; // Bare JID
        var sid = Cookies.get(chatObj.userName + '_sid'); // Session Identifier
        var rid = Cookies.get(chatObj.userName + '_rid'); // Request Identifier

        var connection = new Strophe.Connection(chatObj.xmppHttpBindURL);
        chatObj.connection = connection;

        if(chatObj.isEmpty(sid) && chatObj.isEmpty(rid)){
            connection.connect(jid, chatObj.password, chatObj.onConnection);
        } else {
            // parseInt(rid,10) + 1
            var rid = parseInt(rid) + parseInt(1);
            connection.attach(jid, sid, rid, chatObj.onConnection);
        }
    };

    this.onConnection = function(status) {
        if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
            chatObj.log("CONNECTED ");
            //Cookies.set(chatObj.userName + '_sid', chatObj.connection.sid);
            //Cookies.set(chatObj.userName + '_rid', chatObj.connection.rid);
            jQuery(document).trigger('connected');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
            jQuery(document).trigger('disconnected');
            chatObj.log("DISCONNECTED ");
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
            chatObj.log("CONNFAIL ");
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.AUTHENTICATING) {
            chatObj.log("AUTHENTICATING ");
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL) {
            chatObj.log("AUTHFAIL ");
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.ERROR) {
            chatObj.log("ERROR ");
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.ATTACHED){
            chatObj.log("ATTACHED ");
            jQuery(document).trigger('connected');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL){
            chatObj.log("CONNFAIL ");
        }
    };


$(window).unload(function() {
    console.log("widows unload ");
    if( chatObj.connection != null ){
        console.log("set cookies ");
        Cookies.set(chatObj.userName + '_sid', chatObj.connection.sid);
        Cookies.set(chatObj.userName + '_rid', chatObj.connection.rid);
    } else {
//        Cookies.remove(chatObj.userName + '_sid');
//        Cookies.remove(chatObj.userName + '_rid');
    }
});
```

[404 Invalid SID value in Strophe while using attach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063344/404-invalid-sid-value-in-strophe-while-using-attach)

I tried using windows unload but it does not work. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `attach()` method there is also the `restore` feature in conjunction with the `keepalive` option:

```
var connection = new Strophe.Connection(chatObj.xmppHttpBindURL, {'keepalive': true});
```

...

```
try {
    connection.restore(jid, onConnect);
} catch(e) {
    if (e.name !== "StropheSessionError") { throw(e); }
}
```

See: http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.14/files/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.restore

and

https://github.com/strophe/strophejs/blob/master/examples/restore.js

---

For some strange reasons `sid` and `rid` properties are undefined, so you can retrieve them in the following way:

```
  var sid = chatObj.connection._proto.sid;
  var rid = chatObj.connection._proto.rid;
```

Another way is to retrieve them directly from each XML message sent to connection overriding [xmlOutput](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.14/files/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.xmlOutput) function:

```
  connection.xmlOutput = function (e) {
      rid = $(e).attr('rid');
      sid = $(e).attr('sid');
  };
```

Comment: I do get the sid and rid values properly. Even then it does not work.

Comment: Which version of strophe.js do you use in your project?

Comment: The strophe version I am using is  1.2.14

Comment: Did you try restore instead of attach method? (see my updated answer)

Comment: so, i do not need to call connect at all?

Comment: Thanks. Using restore it worked. Any idea on this new question I added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588494/how-to-create-persistent-rooms-in-openfire-using-strophe?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue while connecting to the XMPP server.
*

> I was using Strophe version 1.2.2.

*

After using the current version, this issue fixed for me.